# Contradiction between doc and schema for Dependabot with pnpm

Tags: github, dependabot, github-dependabot

When configuring Dependabot to use pnpm as package ecosystem, the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#pnpm) states that it is currently supported. Though, I get an error in my editor because it does not exist in the [schema](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/7e278b8be81ca096767221e63e6405509af16369/src/schemas/json/dependabot-2.0.json#L68-L88). What is going on?

Also, Dependabot doesn't seem to understand my configuration file as it wants to create a new one. I assume it might be because of this?

Here is my `.github/dependabot.yml` file:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
  - package-ecosystem: "pnpm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

`pnpm` should be a valid value in the schema as the documentation says.

Comment: They don't say `"pnpm"` is a valid value. Per the table in the docs the correct value for pNpm is `package-ecosystem: "npm"`.

Comment: Oh, I got it now! I just didn't see that `YAML value` column, how stupid! Thank you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes please, make it a post so I can mark it as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pnpm *is* supported, but note (emphasis mine):

> The following table shows, for each package manager:
>
> - The YAML value to use in the `dependabot.yml` file
> - ...
>
> | Package manager | YAML value | Supported versions | Private repositories | Private registries | Vendoring |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | pnpm | **`npm`** | v7, v8 | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |

So you want:

```yaml
 - package-ecosystem: "npm"
```

"Package ecosystem" is broader than the specific package manager you're using, so npm, pnpm and Yarn are all considered part of the `"npm"` ecosystem. Within that the appropriate actions are taken by looking for e.g. `pnpm-lock.yaml` to determine which specific files are relevant.